# Is it mandatory to use Group Policy to install or deploy applications?

Tags: group-policy

Using Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials on 1 server and about 5 workstations, do I have to use GPO to "deploy" the applications?  i.e. CorelDraw, Adobe CS6, Office, Acrobat, etc.

Or can I just go to each workstation (sneakernet) and install them individually?  I'd prefer to do it this way to make sure everything is installed fine.  Or would I lose the Group Policy control here doing it this way?

Is there any pros or cons to doing it these ways?

thank you!

Comment: `Is it mandatory to use Group Policy to install or deploy applications?` - No. `would I lose the Group Policy control here doing it this way?` - Yes.

Comment: Thank you for being concise with that answer.  So if I want the control, then GPO it is.  thank you.

Comment: Your comment I also consider an answer to my questions.  Thank you Joe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a Windows domain administrator it is up to you on how you choose to manage your environment.  There are pros and cons to every choice.  In a large environment manual tasks are frowned upon, as they will take up a lot of time.  Group policy and automation will make your job much easier.

If you prefer to install everything manually, go ahead and do that.  You are the administrator and what you decide goes.

Here are a couple of basic links regarding GPOs and installing software packages:

http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/8595-deploy-msi-s-through-your-network-with-gpo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zadvca6LlzA

Comment: Very small office here.  5± users.  therefore the reasoning not to complicate this any more than it should be as I am finding out moving to a server is just becoming much more headache than there was before.  I need the server for basic things such as backups, networking the workstations, and some sort of control of what the employees do and cannot do.  I just need it kept simple.  Thanks for the links, I'll check them out and keep learning!

Comment: No problem.  If you are looking to control the employees' actions on the systems, you will want to learn and implement group policy. I suggest keep reading/researching and ask questions when you cannot find solutions online or through IT colleagues or friends.

Comment: yes, still in the new process of reading up and learning about the server realm.  I am very fluent in pc tech, but servers I never had a need for until now.  For the most part, Essentials is pretty straight forward, but then there are things that ar eleft to be desired...therefore I am here looking for help in those areas I am unfamiliar with completely.  thank you for your help!

Comment: The video was very helpful and straight forward.  I figured it would be like most pc/windows things, but I just never really looked at GPO yet to know.  What is the difference between Computer Configuration and User Configuration for software installation?  What are the major difference and pros/cons.  Software types that are better for one over the other configurations?  i.e. Adobe Photoshop, Acrobat, Chrome, Office, specialized software (that may have dongle keys, serial no., online or email activation) used in connection with manufacturing devices, etc.

Comment: Please read here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738858%28WS.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: VERY helpful again! Much appreciated bentek! ; )